# Inserting an image into the frame of the device

Tags: swiftui

I have png images of devices. You need to insert images on the device screen. I did it through ZStack, but even if you set the right image sizes, it turns out bad

```
 Image(viewModel.device.name)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(height: viewModel.canvasWidth / 1.40)
                                .background(
                                    viewModel.screenShot?
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: viewModel.contentMode)
                                        .frame(height: viewModel.canvasWidth / 1.45)
                                        .cornerRadius((viewModel.canvasWidth / 1.25) / 15)
                                ).clipped()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! I'm afraid it is unclear from your question and the code you provided what you are trying to achieve and what is not working. Could you, perhaps, expand on what "it turns out bad" means technically?

Comment: I need to put images on the device screen. that is, what would the image fit into the frame of the screen does not go out of them.
Sorry for my english

Comment: You would have to know the size of the device image, and then either crop or scale the image you want to go "on the device screen" so that it is the same size as the device image.

Comment: @aiv Oh, I see, so you have a picture of a device with transparent regions (say, a PNG image) some part of that image corresponds to the device screen. You want to place some other image where the device screen is, but you don't want that other image to show in other areas that could be transparent. Even that explanation is complex :)

Comment: @aiv Is this, roughly, what you meant: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/a11de03546482db1f6ee09af14575feb